# Generic ResourceController with FormRequests in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement a generic resource controller which can respond to basic index/show/store/update/destroy calls.

I'd like to be able to pass a specific FormRequest class to this controller which validates input for store and update calls. However I haven't been able to get this last bit to work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    private $model; //Resource this controller configures.
    private $formRequest; //A FormRequest for validating resource input.
    private $requestParams; //The possible parameters for resource input.

    public function __construct(String $modelClass, String $formRequestClass, array $requestParams){
        $this->model = $modelClass;
        $this->formRequest = $formRequestClass;
        $this->requestParams = $requestParams;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->model::all();
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->model::create(request($this->requestParams));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return $this->findResource($id);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource.
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $resource = $this->findResource($id);
        $resource->update(request($this->requestParams));
        return $resource;
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->findResource($id)->delete();
    }

    private function findResource($id){
        return $this->model::find($id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add this inside the form in your view. It will generate a hidden token input

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Secondly, this is how a store method could look

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
      'title' => 'required'
      'body' => 'required'
    ]);

   Model::create($request->all()->except('_token'));

   return redirect()->back();    
}
```

Or like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'title' => 'required'
      'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    Model::create($request->all()->except('_token'));

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The same for update

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'title' => 'required'
      'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    Model::create($request->all()->except('_token'));


    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Add this in the view

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I'm trying to abstract the validation logic into more specific classes, in order to maintain the advantages of form requests and to keep a seperation of concerns.